# grub - advance to the next drive

Tags: virtual-machine, grub, boot-loader

I've got /dev/sda and /dev/sdb, each with it's own MBR on a virtualized Linux server environment.

I'd like to instruct grub on /dev/sda while booting to skip "self" and proceed booting off of /dev/sdb, whatever is there.

I'm sure this is possible to do and am looking for the magic grub statements.

I've tried the following but grub complains about missing OS

```
root (hd1,0)
chainloader +1
```